# Relevent files not showing up in Dash after restore

Tags: 16.04, unity-dash

After doing a [crashplan](https://www.crashplan.com/en-us/) restore, **relevant** files are not showing up in Dash search. How do I fix this?

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Here I'd expect to see *Module_4.pdf* in my Desktop folder. But I see the recent files I opened.

UPDATE: I can search songs by going to the music tab.

Comment: Maybe you should try the answer i gave you if you want because probably is a software issue reinstalling everything plus upgrade should probably solve this, you will not lose anything that includes your data AND settings

Comment: The recent files touched is what Dash is about. Why would you expect Module_4.pdf to show up?

Comment: @GoldHaloWings It didn't work.

Comment: The truth is that im not familiar with touched files maybe you can explain me or you can wait for another person to help i don't want to look like that i didn't care plus i dont't use the unity UI

Answer (score -1):

**Im not familliar with crashplan** BUT we will try to restore everything without losing any data this **it will NOT wipe your disk** it will just REinstall all software again plus upgrade.

Press **Ctrl+Alt+F1**

Type your **Username** and **Password**

```
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Hope it helps

Comment: What is the relevance of this to the user's question?